# I want to list all values in a range where adjacent cell value have:1) time difference is less than 24hour, and other cells 2) equal specific text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[TABLE + DESIRED RESULT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W3pEO.png)
This is what I got but not sure why it doesn't work:

Formula entered in Sheet2!A2=

```
index($A$2:$A$100, match(0,if(OR(AND(now()-Sheet1!O2<1,D2="closed"),D2="Pending",""),0))
```

Show me the list of cells in Sheet1! when **Condition 1**: Now - Time in O2 < 1 Day & D2 = "closed"

Or **Condition 2**: D2 = "Pending"

Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I got it, this is an array formula so you want to copy it into cell G2 and press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER, then drag the formula down far enough to hold all the results. I changed the condition from "Open, waiting, pending or closed within the last 24 hours" to "not closed more than 24 hours ago" to make it easier to read

formula for G2 is:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$11, SMALL(IF(NOT((C$2:C$11="Closed")*(NOW()-D$2:D$11>1)), ROW(A$2:A$11)-ROW(A$2)+1), ROWS(A$2:A2))), "")
```

The SMALL function looks like this =SMALL(array, n) and returns the nth smallest element of the array. In our case n is given by ROWS(A$2:A2) which will give the row number of the current row in the result output. i.e. the first row of your results will contain the 1st smallest number, the 2nd row will contain the 2nd smallest number etc, the trick is that its not giving the smallest number in the id list but its giving the smallest number in the array defined by this line:

```
IF(NOT((C$2:C$11="Closed")*(NOW()-D$2:D$11>1)), ROW(A$2:A$11)-ROW(A$2)+1
```

This part is a little complicated as its all array formulas/logic. Please note the * in this context represents a logical AND. If you want to understand it better you can highlight just this part of the formula in the formula bar in Excel and press F9, this will show the values of the array. Clicking in cell G2 and highlighting the line above gives this:

{1;FALSE;3;4;5;FALSE;FALSE;8;9;10}

You can see that the resulting array contains the row number for rows that meet the condition and FALSE for those who don't. The INDEX and SMALL functions then display the id of the row with the 1st smallest value then the second etc with the FALSE's used to ignore the rows that don't meet the condition.

Comment: Man this is awesome. "its not giving the smallest number in the id list but its giving the smallest number in the array" is big part of the logic

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1ctDmcvK-DWd1YyQkVBcFJNeWM

Comment: Man that is awesome. I hope this was challenging enough for you :-) "its not giving the smallest number in the id list but its giving the smallest number in the array" does explain most part of the logic around it. 

I was able to replicate the formula on one sheet, but NOT when I use it in a separate sheet, do you mind checking where the mistake is? I am sure the formula is fine, I might be missing sthg else I am not aware of .

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1ctDmcvK-DWd1YyQkVBcFJNeWM/view?usp=sharing

Comment: hey man, you just had a typo in your formula, right at the end it should be a call to ROWS not ROW. The ROW function gives you the row number of a cell but ROWS gives you the number of rows in a range, it's almost the same thing in this case but with ROW it was counting 2, 3, 4.. where we want it to start at 1. Remember to press CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER once you copy the formula in as well. It was challenging too, learned some new things :) feel free to 'accept' my answer as that is a pretty useful formula

Comment: awesome! this is going to help me a lot.

Comment: Hey @lllpratll Can you advise on this. I now am looking for the CLOSED and RESOLVED which have todays' date. I remove the NOT and added the OR.
 =ArrayFormula(IFERROR(INDEX(Data!A$2:A$400, SMALL(IF(or((Data!D$2:D$400="Closed")*(NOW()-Data!O$2:O$400<1),(Data!D$2:D$400="Resolved")*(NOW()-Data!O$2:O$400<1)), ROW(Data!A$2:A$400)-ROW(Data!A$2)+1), ROWS(Data!A$2:A2))), ""))

Comment: Because the condition is inside the array formula you can't use the regular logical operators i.e. you can see in my formula above I have used * in place of AND. Instead of using OR like normal as in this example OR(condition_1,condition_2) you need to format it like this ((condition_1) + (condition_2)>0). This page explains http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/12/04/logical-operations-in-array-formulas/

Comment: Good to know! My learning curve is rocketing! Unfortunately I was not able to make it work: https://gmkr.io/s/580675cd8421f4384dc9a76c/0 Here is a link to the file:https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bFyj-poIbzblURNkuzYyjA_90f6V3oPz4XoVgVqQjSM/edit?usp=sharing Can you guys let me know what I am doing wrong? This looks pretty straight forward.

Comment: Oh got it, totally remove the OR. Thanks Master!

Comment: Hey guys can you help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40166146/get-distinct-list-index-if-adjacent-value-equals-a-specific-text-in-excel/40181130#40181130 ?

Answer (score 0):

syntax error
you have:

```
AND(now()-Sheet1!O2<1, D2="closed")
```

which is fine, problem is in your OR statement:

```
OR(AND(now()-Sheet1!O2<1,D2="closed"),D2="Pending","")
```

the last parentheses should be before the last comma I believe. Currently you have an OR statement with 3 arguments the last of which is "" which isn't going to give you what you want. I think you intended the "" to be the result of the IF statement not a condition for the OR statement, try this:

```
if(OR(AND(now()-Sheet1!O2<1, D2="closed"), D2="Pending"),"",0)
```

Comment: this is what I have, I have fixed the parenthesis but still not working for me
`=index(DATA!$A$2:$A$1000, match(0,if(OR(AND(now()-DATA!O2<1,DATA!D2="closed"),DATA!D2="Pending",DATA!D2="Waiting on Third Party", DATA!D2="Waiting on Customer",DATA!D2="Open", "",0))))`
What am I missing?
I want the list if (time frame <1day and cell is closed), or cell is pending, or cell is Waiting for customer, or cell is waiting for third party.

Comment: you haven't fixed the parentheses sorry, the OR statement works like this:

OR(condition1, condition2, condition3, ...)

so the first condition of your OR statement is your AND statement, the second condition is data!D2="Pending", your third condition is the waiting on third party etc. Since you don't close the parentheses until the end of the line you are using "" and , 0 as conditions as well, like I said I'm guessing those are supposed to be the results of the IF statement (which currently has no results)..

you need a ) after D2="Open" and before the ,

Comment: after watching many videos, I think I might be on the wrong track. I added an image of my table in the description, with the desired result in column F. Am I using the right functions?

`=INDEX($A$2:$A$11,MATCH(0,IF(OR(AND(NOW()-D2<1,C2="closed"),C2="pending",C2="Waiting on Customer"),"",0)))`

Comment: Ok I understand a little better now, you want a list in column F which is effectively a filtered set of your list in column A. Do you need to solve it specifically using INDEX and MATCH? I would approach this differently.. I would add another column after D which has your checks/conditions and would show TRUE or FALSE for every row, then you just need to filter it to only show TRUE and copy the list to column F, would this work for you?

Comment: That won't work. I will have to import and export the data daily to the first sheet. My plan is to automatically get the list in a second sheet, and a report in a 3rd sheet based on the 2nd sheet. I have to do this on a daily basis which is why I have the Now()-created_date condition.

Comment: are you able to use VBA code to achieve this?
it is very difficult to get a list of unknown length as a result using just excel formulas

Comment: Unfortunately not! I have to do this in Google sheet

Comment: ok I think this example does pretty much exactly what you want:

http://www.exceltactics.com/make-filtered-list-sub-arrays-excel-using-small/

like I said its difficult, have a crack using this though and i'll help out if u need :)

Comment: Would I need not to use the small function in my case?  Tried to replicate but I think I have to change couple things compared to his example.

Comment: ok ill try solve it, one thing though, in your pic you show the top row 1492 in the result but it doesn't meet the condition, your condition is going to give you a list of:

all id's waiting, pending or closed within the last 24 hours

result list should be the same as it is minus 1492 right?

Comment: Open, waiting, pending or closed within the last 24 hours. Thanks for you help man. I am curious on whether you are using the SMALL in the function.