# get distinct list (index) if adjacent value equals a specific text in excel

Tags: excel, indexing

I would like to get a distinct list of column J if cell in H of same row equals "No Company".

I tried =IFERROR(INDEX($J$2:$J$10, MATCH(0, COUNTIF($K$1:K2, $J$2:$J$10&"") + IF(ISTEXT($H$2:$H$10)="No company",1,0), 0)), ""))

also tried =IFERROR(INDEX(J$2:J$400, SMALL(IF((H$2:H$400=No company)>1)), ROW(j$2:j$400)-ROW(j$2)+1), ROWS(j$2:j2)), "") changing some of the fields but no luck

[Desired result + Try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhK2T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Create a new function:
open VBA Editor (alt + F11), add new module, insert code:

```
Function JoinAll(ByRef range As range, ByVal delimiter As String)
  For Each c In range.Cells
  If InStr(JoinAll, c.Value) = 0 Then
    JoinAll = JoinAll + c.Value + delimiter
  End If
  Next
  JoinAll = Left(JoinAll, Len(JoinAll) - Len(delimiter))
End Function
```

use formula like this:

```
=JoinAll(J2:J10, ", ")
```